How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \,(x\ln^2x)$?
I was solving some Integral using contour technique where I needed to evaluate following limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \,(x\ln^2x)$$
Since its $0\times\infty$ indeterminate form I tried to convert it into $0/0$ form So that I can use L'Hopital technique to evaluate this:
\begin{align*}
L&=\lim_{x \to 0} \,(x\ln^2x)\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \,\frac{x}{\frac{1}{\ln^2x}}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \,\frac{1}{\frac{-2}{x\ln^3x}}\\
&=-2\lim_{x \to 0} \,x\ln^3x\\
\end{align*}
Which is again same $0\times\infty$ form.
Any idea how to evaluate this?

What about using $\frac{\ln^2 x}{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Letting $y=-\ln x,$ you get $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y^2}{e^y}.$ Then use that $e^y>\frac{y^3}6.$

You used the wrong form. Put $\frac{1}{x}$ in the nominator so $\frac{\ln^2(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}$, than twice L'Hopital will come out with $0$.

Thanks for the help
